Why are there so many links to internal storage on android?
So after looking around, I found /sdcard, /storage/self/primary, /storage/emulated/0, /storage/sdcard0. and as of now I don't have root access so I can't check but as far as I remember there was one in /data too. so im wondering why are there so many symlinks to the same place? is there any difference between them?

That is true, there are many other entries that seem to target the same internal storage for Android devices.
Types :

/sdcard: This is a legacy path that was earlier used in Android releases before Android 10 to refer to the device’s primary external storage, which is an SD card.

/storage/self/primary: It was added in Android 10 (API level 29) as a recommended alternative to the ‘Android’ path for accessing the primary internal storage of devices.

/storage/emulated/0: This is a copy that functions as a link to the real location of the files. That is a common way to reach the internal storage of many applications. Typically, it points to /storage/self/primary.

/storage/sdcard0: This path may sometimes be available on devices with older Android versions or certain custom ROMs. This refers to the same directory as /sdcard or /storage/emulated/0 folder but is not preferred in newer versions of Android OSs.

/data/media/0: This is an internal path which also points to the primary user’s emulated storage. It’s usually not available without using root privilege.


Why So Many Links?

Backward Compatibility: Micro SD card supports compatibility with legacy programs still using this path.

Standardization: The reliable path – /storage/self/primary – provides common naming for all devices and Android versions.

User Profiles: The emulated storage system in android is convenient in the sense that it supports multiple user profiles and each user can have his or her own storage. Subdirectories such as /storage/emulated/{user_id} make these partitions possible.

Abstraction: /storage/emulated/0 is therefore an abstraction layer, which would make the system capable of changing the storage path under the hood but without impacting the apps that depend on this path.


The /data directory partitions apps and their data and settings but no user files. It is not usually used for general file storage and most of the apps might not be able to access it.
Note :

In most cases on modern Android devices from Android 10 and above you can use /storage/self/primary or /storage/emulated/0 to reach the internal storage.

The old /sdcard is only to maintain backward compatibility.

These paths often refer to the same destination and can motivate future upgrades.

The /data is a directory that has a different purpose from the internal path (to store application data).


If you understand the various paths and their intentions on Android, you can determine which path will be appropriate for your program’s requirement.

Reference links :
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage
https://medium.com/@babul.sust.cse/understanding-of-android-storage-system-17b6134f873
https://source.android.com/docs/core/storage
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-overview-of-android-storage/
